# Log.e creating some issue in Interceptor

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, interceptor

This is my interceptor code for unauthorized checking.

```
class UnauthorizedInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private Context context;

    UnauthorizedInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        Log.e("response: ", response.body().string()); // creating problem
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ServerResponse serverResponse = objectMapper.readValue(response.body().string(), ServerResponse.class);
        if (serverResponse.getErrorCode() == 401) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(R.string.unauthorized_user);
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }

    private class UnauthorizedException extends IOException {

        UnauthorizedException(final int stringRes) {
            super(context.getString(stringRes));
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, stringRes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

If I use `Log.e` in Interceptor then I am not getting any response in the Retrofit success callback. But `Log.e` prints the response in the logcat properly. After that, it's not giving any callback to the Retrofit success callback.It goes to the error callback and giving `IllegalStateException:closed`.

But if I commented out the `Log.e` the code in the interceptor then it's working fine.

Why it's happening? Can anyone please explain this thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Log.e line seems to be corrupted. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev Updated. Sorry I missed a bracket while typing in stackoverflow.

Comment: Your Log.e is wrong. It should be in your case **Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response.body().string());**

Comment: @Ruan_Lopes, i don't think the problem lies in this, since the method takes acceptable arguments anyway and it can not interrupt the code execution

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev agreed, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `response.body()` 1 single time.
When doing so, it consumes the internal variables, so afterwards they're null.
So you should save the value from that call to a variable, and then use that when getting information from it/logging it.

Comment: Got it. I searched by response.body() can be called single time and got the proper answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation of `response.body()` method:

> Returns a non-null value if this response was passed to {@link
>   Callback#onResponse} or returned from {@link Call#execute()}. Response
>   bodies must be {@linkplain ResponseBody closed} and may be consumed
>   only once.
>
> This always returns null on responses returned from {@link#cacheResponse}, {@link#networkResponse}, and {@link #priorResponse()}.

I am adding a Github issue link also. This will help you more regarding this issue.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1240